# Floor function problem

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Prove that the two numbers $\lfloor ax \rfloor$, $\lfloor bx \rfloor$ for $x=1,2,3,\dots$ comprise of all integers $1,2,3,\dots$, without repetition if $a$ and $b$ are positive irrational numbers such that $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}=1$.

I am unable to solve this problem.

Comment: I am new to stackexhange

Comment: "I am new to stackexhange" Maybe you are, and so what?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would help,

Assume $[ax]=[by]=n$ for some positive integer n. Note that since a and b are irrational, we cannot have $ax=n$ or $by=n$. Hence, we have the strict inequalities:

$$n < ax < n+1 $$ and $$ n < by < n+1 $$

By dividing the first inequality by a, the second by b, then adding them and using the relation $\dfrac{1}{a} + \dfrac{1}{b} =1$ to get:

$$n < x+y < n+1$$

But $x+y$ is an integer. Hence this is a contradiction and we cannot have repetition.

Now let us assume that there exists an n such that neither $[ax]$ nor $[bx]$ equals n for any x. Let p and q be the largest integers such that $ap, bq<n$. Then we have the following inequalities:

$$ ap < n < n+1 < a(p+1)$$
And,
$$ bq < n < n+1 < b(q+1)$$

Again dividing the first by a and second by b, we get,

$$ p+q < n < n+1 < p+q+2$$

But clearly this is not possible. Hence, the proof is done.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful solution